# Can't Remove Image from CCK File Field when editing node (Throbber just spins)

Tags: 7, entities, files, javascript, media

I was able to upload an image, but the thumbnail didn't appear until I hit save on the form.  When I try to remove the image, it just sits there spinning the throbber; if I click on "Save" in the form, the image is not removed.

I think this has to do with AJAX getting caught up somewhere, but I don't know how to go about troubleshooting this.

Do you have any idea? I've tried switching the field from "Bar with progress meter" to "Throbber" and that didn't help.

Edit:

I forgot that I updated jQuery to the latest version and used some special code to prevent it from affecting the backend.  Here is the jquery_update_jquery_path() function from jquery_update.module (I modified it to fix this issue by checking for 'edit' in the uri):

```
function jquery_update_jquery_path() {
  $curr_uri = request_uri();
  if (strpos($curr_uri, 'admin') > 0 || strpos($curr_uri, 'edit') > 0) {
  $jquery_file = array('none' => 'jquery.js', 'min' => 'jquery.min.js');
  return JQUERY_UPDATE_REPLACE_PATH .'/'. $jquery_file[variable_get('jquery_update_compression_type', 'min')];
  }
  else {
  $jquery_file = array('none' => 'jquery-1.5.2.js', 'min' => 'jquery-1.5.2.min.js');
  return JQUERY_UPDATE_REPLACE_PATH .'/'. $jquery_file[variable_get('jquery_update_compression_type', 'min')];
  }
}
```

Comment: I was able to delete the images by disabling JavaScript.  Hopefully this is only a temporary solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of JQuery are you running? I had an AJAX issue (was trying to rebuild derivative images for all nodes of a specific node-type) when using JQuery 1.5.1 instead of the version that is shipped with Drupal 6. Removing 1.5.1 and adding the stock version of JQuery resolved the issue.

Comment: That's totally expected as you really shouldn't use jQuery 1.5.1 or any version above 1.3.2 with Drupal 6. There's a reason jQuery Update module only goes as far as 1.3.2! :)

Comment: The OP didn't report he installed the latest version of jQuery, which is not what I would expect somebody does. If he really did that, I would expect that not being able to delete an uploaded image is the last of his problems. `;-)`

Comment: I used jQuery update with modified code that kept the old version of jQuery on any uri with admin in it, I just forgot to include an exception for edit.  So yes, thank you for reminding me that jQuery was the wrong version.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to say it was probably permission-related (no delete permission) but if you managed by turning off javascript than its definitely not that.

Turn on firebug, enable the console & turn javascript back on.

If its an ajax error it will show up in the firebug console.

Comment: Throbber-type ajax issues are *often* a problem with the AJAX request, so the suggestion of firebug is perfect.